# if inside a foreach php

Tags: php, if-statement, foreach

Hi I'm having trouble figuring out a way to include if clauses within a foreach.
I'm writing a page that allows the user to see the data they entered in in the previous form before committing it to the database. They can choose to select from data thats previously been entered for different sizes, quantities, etc, as well as entering their own new options. Right now the way I have it set all of the choices appear but they are all on one row and stacked within a cell. My problem is I need it to create a new row and print `$size` and `$side` for each value.

```
<tr>
    <td>
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['var1'])) {
        $var1 = $_POST['var1'];
        foreach($var1 as $value) {
            echo $value . "<br>";
        }
    }
    if(isset($_POST['new_var1'])) {
        $new_var1 = $_POST['new_var1'];
        foreach($new_var1 as $value) {
            echo $value . "<br>";
        }
    }
?>  
    </td>
    <td>
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['var2'])) {
        $var2 = $_POST['var2'];
        foreach($var2 as $value) {
            echo $value . "<br>";
        }
    }    
    if(isset($_POST['new_var2'])) {
        $new_var2 = $_POST['new_var2'];
        foreach($new_var2 as $value) {
            echo $side . "<br>";
        }
    }
?>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Is there a way to inlude `if` statements within a `foreach` so I can check to see what choices are set, then cycle through all the choices at once and then include the `<tr></tr>` tags within the `foreach`? I was thinking of doing it by making multiple `if` statement that check each combination of `isset` for my variables and have `foreach` statements that only include the set choices but that seems very clunky and a roundabout way to do what I need.

Comment: Are `screw_side` and `screw_size` the same length?

Comment: Do you know that you can close and reopen php tags as you like ? eg: <?php if ($test) { ?><br><?php }?>

Comment: @JeromeWAGNER: Why would you do that here?

Comment: @Eric: I am trying to understand the question and the level of expertise of the user. It seems to me that part of the problem comes from the coupling/decoupling of the datas and the html

Comment: The solution you came up with seems clunky because you do not separate logic from presentation. Most of solutions will be clunky in that case.

Answer (score 2):

I don't really understand your situation, but I'd suggest changing your form to be like this:

```
<input name="screws[0][size]" />
<input name="screws[0][side]" />

<input name="screws[1][size]" />
<input name="screws[1][side]" />

<input name="screws[2][size]" />
<input name="screws[2][side]" />
```

When PHP gets that, you can do:

```
<?php
$screws = @$_GET['screws'];
$newscrews = @$_GET['newscrews'];
?>
<table>
    <?php if($screws) foreach($screws as $screw): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $screw['size'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $screw['side'] ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</table>
```

Comment: @ Eric so you suggest changing my form so that all the variables associated with 'screw' are a multidimensional array and then running a foreach through that? so it would be <input name="screw[][size]"><input name="screw[][location]> etc?

Comment: That makes the most sense to me. After all, each `size` field is linked to the `side` field, so it makes sense to have an array of screws, rather than an array for each property. I think you have to put numberic indices in the square brackets though - PHP only infers the index at the end, IIRC.

Comment: @user1440701: You might not have realized, but `@$_GET['screws']` prevents you from having to do `isset`. Instead of giving a key error, it just returns `NULL` if the key is not set.

Comment: Hmm i tried that with this code                                     `$screws = $_POST['screw'];
if($screws) {
foreach($screws as $screw){ ?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $screw['size']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $screw['side']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $screw['location']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $screw['quantity']; ?></td>
</tr>` Now however, in the first row, it will return the size in the first cell, but errors in the next three cells. In the second row, error in the first cell, side in the second, and errors in the next two, and so on and so forth. It ends up making a diagnol line of values across.

Comment: I have a javascript on my form that allows users to add extra inputs for another screw so I cant really use number indices in my input names, before i had them set like `<input name="screw_size[]">` so if they added another screw it would just tack on. Now my input names are like `<input name="screw[size][]">` and im getting an undefined index error.

Comment: I got it to work by using this `for` loop, not really the best of solutions, but its functional. `$screws = $_POST['screw'];
$num = count($screws['size']);
 for($i=0;$i<$num;$i++){
?> <tr>
  <td><?php echo $screws['size'][$i]; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $screws['side'][$i]; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $screws['location'][$i]; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $screws['quantity'][$i]; ?></td>
 </tr>
<?php
}`

Comment: You're muddling things. `screws[n][side]` where n is an integer says "set the `side` property of the nth screw". `screws[][side]` says "set the side property of the next entry in the array". As such, you end up setting the size of the first one, then the location of the second, ... etc. `screw[size][]` gives you an undefined index error because your array is transposed - you've gained nothing over `screw_size[]`.

Comment: I understand that, however i cant create the input names as `screw[1][size]...screw[1][side]....screw[2][size]...screw[2][side]` because i have code that adds an infinite amount of new inputs. i thought i could name them as `screw[][size]...screw[][side]` but your right, its writing `size` as `screw[1][size]` and `side` as `screw[2][side]` how can i force the first inputs, `screw[][size], screw[][side]`, to come out as `screw[1][size], screw[1][side]` the second to be `screw[2][size] screw[2][side]` etc. etc.?

Comment: _"i cant create the input names as ... because i have code that adds an infinite amount of new inputs"_ - you could change that code!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, conditionals are allowed in `foreach` statements. You'd include them normally.
Also, the code you have is vulnerable to XSS (cross site scripting) attacks. You may want to sanitize the data being submitted by post.

I'm sorry if I misunderstood the question, it's worded a bit.. interestingly..

EDIT: `if(isset($var1) && isset($var2) &&...etc)`

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution using your existing data format:

```
<?php
$sizes = @$_GET['screw_sizes'];
$sides = @$_GET['screw_sides'];
$screws = array()

if($sides && $sizes) {
    $n = min(count($sizes), count($sides))
    for ($i=0; $i < $n; $i++) {
        $screws[$i]['side'] = $sides[$i];
        $screws[$i]['size'] = $sizes[$i];
    }
}
?>
```

The way to echo it out is the same:

```
<table>
    <?php foreach($screws as $screw): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $screw['size'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $screw['side'] ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</table>
```